# Zend Framework - Access view inside plugin

Tags: zend-framework

How to access view inside plugin.

For example i have language plugin and i need to add to add javascript language array depending on language plugin output.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways, depends what you want to do.

You can grab view from `viewRenderer` which you can get from `HelperBroker`.

```
$vr = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$view = $vr->getView();
```

You may also try to get it as application resource from boostrap:

```
$view = $this->getActionController()->getInvokeArg('view');
```

or

```
$front = $this->getFrontController();
$view = $front->getParam('boostrap')->getResource('view');
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 6):

BTW this works on my project:

```
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Layout')
       ->getView()
```

But this doesn't work:

```
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')
       ->getView()
```

Maybe because the layout is enabled.